# React router v5 : 3rd level of nesting is not recognising path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, url-routing

I am creating an app which requires multiple level of nesting. from 3rd level my routes are not getting recognised.

App JS

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Home JS

```js
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <ContentNav />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/clients">
            <Clients />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/publishers">
            <Publishers />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Redirect to="/clients" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Clients JS

```js
class Clients extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        Clients Page
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/add">
            <AddClient />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/edit">
            <AddClient />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Entity />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

these routers are rendering same component  
*http://localhost:3000/clients* 
*http://localhost:3000/clients/add* 
*http://localhost:3000/clients/edit*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react nested urls are not relative, have to specify absolute path :

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="clients/add">
        <AddClient />
    </Route>
    <Route path="clients/edit">
        <AddClient />
    </Route>
    <Route path="clients/">
        <Entity />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```